# Asynchronous DataProvider, CellTable, Pager "Last page Button"

Tags: gwt, asynchronous, pager, dataprovider, celltable

I'm using a CellTable with a Page and an Asynchronous DataProvider. Everthing works fine expect, the "last Page" button of the page is disabled.
This may be because of the Asynchronous DataProvider, could deliver additional data, and therefore doesn't know how many records he will have and what the last page is. However I know when the data delivery is finished, so then I could display the last page.

How can I tell the Asynchronous DataProvider, that there is no more data and he should display the last page Button?

BR,
Stefan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, using a SimplePager with uiBinder.
The default constructor for SimplePager shows a forward button, not a last page one...

I then use @UiField(provided=true) for the SimplePager, and use the following constructor:

```
pager = new SimplePager(TextLocation.LEFT, (Resources) GWT.create(SimplePager.Resources.class), false, 0, true);
```

which match:

```
public SimplePager(TextLocation location,
  Resources resources, boolean showFastForwardButton,
  final int fastForwardPages, boolean showLastPageButton)
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to set the `exact` flag in the [updateRowCount(count,exact)](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/view/client/AsyncDataProvider.html#updateRowCount%28int,%20boolean%29) function to true?

Also make sure that you call the update function in this order:

```
setRowCount(length, true);
setRowData(0, data);
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer to the question.  I would also add the caveat that you need to pull the count for the query and the limited set of data back as well (unless you have a limited data set).  ```{metadata:{count:120000,offset:20},data:[entry1,entry2,entry3] }```